# How to set up Core Data on watchOS 2

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, watchkit, watchos-2

What is the process of setting up Core Data on an Apple Watch counterpart?

I understand that there will be seperate .xcdatamodeld files, but what is are all the files and code that need to be added into the counterpart to make it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing Core Data to watchOS 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096785/implementing-core-data-to-watchos-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same way you do this in iOS apps. You will need to add xcdatamodeld file to your Watch extension target and setup all the CoreData components (`NSManagedObjectModel`, `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`, `NSManagedObjectContext`) in code the same way you do it in iOS apps.